# How to reference an bibliography item but not as a citation

Tags: bibliographies, captions, citing, natbib

The citation style in my document uses superscripts for the reference number. I would like to reference a bibliography item in-line once using just the reference number. I'm sure this is a simple thing to do, I just don't know how to phrase this question for google. I'm using natbib and the references are set up in the preamble with:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage[numbers, super,sort&compress, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

I want my graphic caption to say this (I have underlined in red the portion of the caption i need help with):
[image]

The latex snippet that generated this is simple:

```
\begin{figure}[hb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 5in]{ch1_ehtylene_MO.png}
\caption{[Rest of Text] ...  Reproduced from reference 20. Copyright (2002) National Academy of Sciences}
\label{ch1_mo}
\end{figure}
```

What I want is to use a command to reference the bibliography with the result the reference number inline so that way it updates as I continue editing my document. something like \cite:

```
\begin{figure}[hb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 5in]{ch1_ehtylene_MO.png}
\caption{[Rest of Text] ...  Reproduced from reference \cite{ethylene}. Copyright (2002) National Academy of Sciences}
\label{ch1_mo}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that using \cite like this ends up with a superscript, which I do not want:
[image]

Is there a command to reference the .bib entry and return the reference number in-line?

Comment: My guess would be `\citenum{<key>}`, but since you didn't share a compilable example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) I didn't test it (so I can't vouch for anything. If it doesn't work, I'd definitely need to see a compilable example document to figure out what is going on, though.).

Comment: \citenum{<key>} does what I want, thank you very much. You didn't need to test it, I just wanted to know if someone knew off-hand a command that did what I described.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\citenum{<key>}` as suggested by moewe works